# Client authorization Mosquitto?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

We want to achieve certain Authorization checks using `Mosquitto` MQTT Broker:

1. The `SAN (Subject Alt Name)` of the client certificate shall contain the `clientID` of the incoming MQTT request.
2. A client shall be able to subscribe only those topics which contain it's `clientID` i.e Topic Authorization.
3. Only known `clientID's` shall be able to subscribe to wildcard topics.

Can these be achieved with configuration changes without changing `Mosquitto` code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you combine both `use_identity_as_username` and `use_username_as_clientid` you can use the CN (note not the SAN) as both the username and client id.
2. That will depend a little on the topic structure, but you can probably use the `%c` pattern to build a ACL entry that will match e.g. `%c/#` will allow all topics starting with the client id
3. The ACLs are controlled by username not client id, but given 1. both should be the same so again this should be possible with the default options.